# Django Unit Test Case

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-unittest

Hello I'm a newbie to Django Unit test as I'm working on Django Rest Framework using modelviewset. I need to test few models, serializers, views & urls. I'm not sure how to perform it. As I have followed few documentations. But still not clear. Here's my code

`models.py`

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """This Class is used to extend the in-build user model """
    ROLE_CHOICES = (('CREATOR','CREATOR'),('MODERATOR','MODERATOR'),('USERS','USERS'))
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('MALE','MALE'),('FEMALE',"FEMALE"),('OTHER','OTHER'))
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date of Birth', null=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/profile_images', verbose_name='Profile Image', default='media/profile_images/default.webp', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(verbose_name='Bio')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Role', choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default='USERS')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, verbose_name='Gender', choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    following = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    followers = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','username','password','email','date_of_birth',
                  'profile_image','bio','role','gender', 'following','followers')
        extra_kwargs = {'is_active':{'write_only':True},
                        'password':{'write_only':True}}
```

`views.py`

```
class UserAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope]
```

`urls.py`

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', views.UserAPI, basename='users'),
router.register('following', views.FollowingAPI, basename='following'),


urlpatterns = router.urls
```

I have written few test cases but getting some errors. `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'UserAPI' not found. 'UserAPI' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` I'm not sure what wrong i have done even in model. So please need your help. Thank you

`tests.py`

```
class UserTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create(
            first_name='John',last_name='Cena',username='john.cena',
            email='john@wwf.com',date_of_birth='1994-12-12', bio='Hello I am John',
            role='MODERATOR',gender='MALE',
        )


    def test_users_model(self):
        first_name = User.objects.get(first_name='John')
        last_name = User.objects.get(last_name='Cena')
        self.assertEquals(first_name.get_username(), "john.cena")

    def test_user_view(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('UserAPI'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertContains(response, 'john.cena')

    def test_user_urls(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [**`docs`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage):

```
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

The example above would generate the following URL patterns:

URL pattern: ^users/$ Name: 'user-list'
URL pattern: ^users/{pk}/$ Name: 'user-detail'
URL pattern: ^accounts/$ Name: 'account-list'
URL pattern: ^accounts/{pk}/$ Name: 'account-detail'
```

The url name you seem to want to use then is `user-list`, but since you used `basename='users'` it would be `users-list` so:

```py
    def test_user_view(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('users-list'))
        # ...
```

Comment: thanks @BrianDestura for the help. It worked. Can you tell about how to add test case for urls?

Comment: Can you expand on that? What did you mean by test case for urls?

Comment: As i'm writing test cases for models, views & serializers. So do i need to write a test cases for urls.py or not

Comment: IMO I don't think that's needed

Comment: Okay thanks alot @Brian for the help.

Comment: Okay so the entire code written from my end is correct or not till now apart from test_views